# Does There Exist a Planar, Linear, Triodic Tree-Like Continuum?

Tags: gn.general-topology

Motivated by [Continuum image of line is chainable?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/302901/continuum-image-of-line-is-chainable)

A planar continuum $X$ is a compact, connected subset of the plane.  It is linear if there is a continuous bijection from $[0,1)$ onto $X$, for example a Warsaw circle.  It is triodic if it contains a simple triod, i.e. three closed arcs all attached at an end point (3-pointed asterisk).  It is tree-like if there is a sequence of surjections $f_n : X \rightarrow T_n$ onto finite trees such that max$[\text{diam}(f_n^{-1}(x))]$ goes to zero.

I strongly suspect no such object exists.  It seems like the 'being tree-like' happens after finite time and then the tail will create a loop in the plane when it comes back around to start converging back onto itself.  The inclusion of a triod then seems like it will cause impossibilities for the bijectiveness criterion of linearity.

Any thoughts?  I found very little overlap in the investigation of linear continua and treelike continua.

Comment: It seems that each linear continuum containing a triod is homeomorphic to the circle with an attached arc, so cannot be tree-like. In the proof one should use the local connectedness of the triod in its central point.

Comment: Do you have a reference?  The dimensionality issue seems to require some subtle facts, e.g. right off the bat we see that such a statement implies things about injectivity and spacefilling curves.

Comment: For a linear continuum the set of accumulation points of the half-line is a compact connected subset $A$ of the half-line. Depending on the form and position of this connected subset, we can distinguish 4 possible topological types of linear continua: if $A$ is a singleton, then the linear continuum is either the circle or the circle with an attached arc; if $A$ is a non-degenerated interval, then the linear continuum is either Warsaw circle or the  Warsaw circle with an attached arc at its end-point. It would be nice to prove such a classification theorem.

Comment: @TarasBanakh Actually, your statement about circles/Warsaw circles is Lemma 4 in "Continua which are a one-to-one continuous image of $[0,\infty)$" by Sam Nadler.

Comment: @David Great! Then it remains to prove that there exists 5 pairwise inequivalent embedding of linear continua in the plane: the Warsaw circle has two non-equivalent embeddings.

Comment: About to read the Nadler, but for the fifth it is the circle and free arc with free arc inside/outside the bounded domain, two Warsaw and the one embedding of the circle (Schoenflies).

Comment: Here is the paper, public access.  https://www.impan.pl/en/publishing-house/journals-and-series/fundamenta-mathematicae/all/75/2/98242/continua-which-a-one-to-one-continuous-image-of-0

Comment: Unfortunately, we forgot about objects such as the M-continuum.  There are many ways to converge onto an arc with a path.